# PayPal IPN - Queued

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using paypal sandbox to do some test payments and they have all been coming though fine until today. I'm not receiving an IPN from paypal and when I check in the IPN notification history all the messages are showing as Queued

If I resend an IPN that has a status of sent I receive that fine but none of the new ones are coming through.

I've checked my error logs on the server and I'm not getting any coding errors.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a backlog on PayPals end?

Comment: Same here... Today IPN messages just show as queued in the sandbox account with no attempts to send them over.

Comment: It's two days and they still are shown as Queued...

Answer (score 0):

I have opened a support ticket at https://de.paypal-techsupport.com case: 160410-000032 to inform them.

I will keep you posted.